# Allowing user to add/remove/order fields and recording in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to add some functionality to my website which allows users to add/remove/put certain fields in order.

For example: There are 5 paragraphs and I want the user to be able to put these in the order they like and also delete some if they do not find them useful.

I know I will have to use jQuery for this (sortable) but need some advice on how to store this order/selected elements in a database (using mysql and php).

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax. Inside database create table UsersParagraphs - 1 row will reflect order numbers of paragraphs for certain user. On your website u can create movable divs (with paragraphs) dynamically using data from table Paragraphs. After change of div order by user, u can this action reflect in table Paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2-dimensional array in JavaScript combined with an index field in the MySQL database, like this:

```
var list_index = new Array();
list_index[0] = [245, 1, 1, 'BMW'];
list_index[1] = [256, 2, 2, 'Porsche'];
```

The first key is the MySQL Index of the entry. The second index key represents the index on the HTML (live) list. The third index key represents the index key in your database. So it can look like this too when you would swap Porsche to the top in your list:

```
list_index[0] = [256, 2, 1, 'BMW'];
list_index[1] = [245, 1, 2, 'Porsche'];
```

Keeping this values in mind you can use jQuery to post the updated the index keys to your PHP code and update them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to me is to have a table "preferences". If you website has limited elements you can have columns defining all of them and a page to manage the preferences of that user.

If your website is quite big and always changing, you migh have to think about defining properties, values and effects in one table, and in preferences store property, value and element that aples.